# Is there any way to add the "tabular" environment to the LaTeX support for this site?

Tags: feature-request

That would allow this structure, instead of trying to build tables with ASCII or UTF-8 characters, tedious to say the least.

```
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
```

The chosen answer below uses the following code, which works for non-numeric cell values as well.

```
\begin{array} \\
  a & b & c \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
```

——————————

\begin{array} \\
  a & b & c \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}

——————————

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax [does not implement tabular](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment). One can [use `array` instead](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6737):
\begin{array}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}

But I usually prefer [text to table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) tool by Senseful, to avoid relying on JavaScript for rendering.

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+
```